# What does It Mean for a Film to be "Stylish"

Tags: terminology

I've come across the phrase stylish a few times while reading movie reviews online. A few examples of what I'm talking about:

- the critics consensus of "X-Men: First Class" is as follows: "With a strong script, **stylish** direction, and powerful performances from its well-rounded cast, X-Men: First Class is a welcome return to form for the franchise".
- Kill Bill Vol. 1 has the critics consensus: "Kill Bill is admittedly little more than a **stylish** revenge thriller -- albeit one that benefits from a wildly inventive surfeit of style."
- John Wick has the following critics consensus: "**Stylish**, thrilling, and giddily kinetic, John Wick serves as a satisfying return to action for Keanu Reeves -- and what looks like it could be the first of a franchise."

What exactly does stylish mean in the context of film?

Comment: Too Broad or Primarily Opinion Based. Take your pick.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the term "stylish" has a *precise* definition in relation to films.  In general it just means the film has some unique property - possibly a character, or a filming technique, or something about the writing / dialogue.  Something that makes it stand out from the crowd.  The word could also be used specifically in reference to the outfits worn by the actors, in which case it would be using its more general definition in relation to fashion or haute-couture.

Of course, the use of this term is highly opinion-based, as are most words used by film critics.

I don't know if you've seen any of the movies you mentioned there, but if you have, I think you might sort of know what the critics meant already.

Kill Bill (like many of Tarantino's films) is chock full of very unique characters, whose interactions often lead to very unique situations.  His films often have several layers of meaning, both symbolic and literal, which leads to a particular "style" that defines them as his.

John Wick used extravangant gun-fu action sequences and the unusual technique of making some words spoken by characters appear visually on screen ("baba yaga") for no particular reason other than emphasis, which creates a very distinct atmosphere while watching the movie.